# Ambari YARN container settings

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, ambari

I'm interested in CPU settings on Ambari, concretely, I see CPU options such as:

> Percentage of physical CPU allocated for all containers on a node
>
> Number of virtual cores

And per container:

> Minimum Container Size (VCores)
>
> Maximum Container Size (VCores)

I saw similar settings regarding the RAM and I was able to find some [recommendations](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/determine-hdp-memory-config.html) about it, but I found none for the case of CPU.

Concretely, I'm interested whether I should keep a number of VCores for the system (as in the case of memory), or should I use it all for containers? That is, **should the Number of virtual cores be set to maximal value** or not? And **what to use as Percentage**?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you keep a minimum of 2 cores per node for the operating system and a minimum of 2 gigs of memory for the same. The remaining you could safely utilise for your applications being launched on yarn. That being said, you can use it all but it might choke your system in case you run extremely cpu intensive jobs.